# Jquery :wrap: placing div side by side

Tags: jquery

I am plotting a graph with large axis ticks like " United States of ameriaca " .
 the issue comes when multiple long ticks start overlapping ,so I wrote a code to implement marquee so that upon mouse over the ticks may scroll otherwise it may just show its few characters .What I am trying to do is through wrapping a element in jquery .But the divs are getting placed one upon another.I need side by side.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title> MyEXP#Scroll</title>

          <script type='text/javascript' src="jquery.js"></script>

        </head>
        <body>
          <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jqplot.js"></script>

         <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.js"></script>

         <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.cursor.js"></script>

         <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.highlighter.js"></script>

         <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.js"></script>

         <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.js"></script>

         <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.js"></script>

         <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisLabelRenderer.js"></script>

         <script language="plugins/jqplot.pointLabels.js"></script>

         <script language="javascript" type="plugins/jqplot.barRenderer.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.enhancedLegendRenderer.js"></script>

        <div id="chart1" style="width:600px; height:400px"></div>
        <div id=".jqplot-mytick">

        <div id=".jqplot-xaxis-tick" >
        </div>
        </div>

         <div id="tick"></div>
         </body>

          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.jqplot.css">

      <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
        $(window).load(function(){
        $(document).ready(function(){

            ticks = ['India is a land of cultural diversity', 'Nepal is famous for its natural beauty', 'United States Of America is a federal system', 'Netherlands has moderate climate', 'United Nation Org', 'srilankaisgood despite of its internal conflict'];

            data = [];

           //  var dataForAxis2 = [132.19,2.99,6.09,50.38,1.44,4.4];

            for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                line = [];     // data for Axis 1
                line1=[];     //  data for Axis 2
               for (j = 0; j < ticks.length; j++)
                {

                   line.push(Math.random());
                   line1.push(ticks[i]);

                }
                data.push(line);
                data.push(line1);
            }

            var opts = { 
        title:{
        text: 'Scroll@JQPlot',
        textColor: '#d8b83f'

        },

        //  -------------------------------Pt1 series colours Begin-------------------
        seriesColors: [ "#ffffff", "#c5b47f", "#EAA228", "#579575", "#839557", "#958c12",
                "#953579", "#4b5de4", "#d8b83f", "#ff5800", "#0085cc"],
        // -------------------------------- Pt 1 series colors Ends---------------------
        axesDefaults: {
        // tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer ,
               tickOptions: {
                    mark: 'outside',    // Where to put the tick mark on the axis
                                        // 'outside', 'inside' or 'cross',
                    showMark: true,
                    showGridline: true, // wether to draw a gridline (across the whole grid) at this tick,
                    markSize:4,        // length the tick will extend beyond the grid in pixels.  For
                                        // 'cross', length will be added above and below the grid boundary,
                    show: true,         // wether to show the tick (mark and label),
                    showLabel: true,    // wether to show the text label at the tick,
                    formatString: '',   // format string to use with the axis tick formatter
                }, 
            },
                axes: {
                    xaxis: {
                        renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                        ticks: ticks,


                    },

                     yaxis: { autoscale:true,
        labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
                                label: 'Population Density -1',



         //--------------------------------pt2 Y axis title1 rotation & color Begin-----------------
                                renderer: $.jqplot.LogAxisRenderer ,                   // pt2 Y axis title rotation

        //Label color Point 3
        labelOptions:{
        textColor: '#d8b83f',
        } 
         //--------------------------------pt2 Y axis title1 rotation& color ends---------------------                 
                            },

                            y2axis: {
                             autoscale:true,
        //-----------------------------------pt2 Yaxis title 2 rotation & color   begins---------------------------
                               labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,    //pt 2  Y axis title rotation

                             label: 'Population Density-2',
        //Label color Point 3

        labelOptions:{
        textColor: '#F0000F',
        } 

        //-----------------------------------pt2 Yaxis title 2 rotation $ color ends---------------------------                        


                            },

                },

         series:[ {yaxis:'yaxis', label:'dataForAxis2' },


                   {yaxis:'y2axis', label:'dataForAxis2'},
                    {label:'Hotel'},
                    {label:'Event Regristration'},
                    {label:'Airfare'},
                     {label:'Helicopter'},
         {label:'Hotel a_1092'},
                    {label:'Event Regristrationb_1298289821sdsdsd'},
                    {label:'Airfare'},
                     {label:'Helicopter'},
         {label:'Hotel'},
                    {label:'Event Regristration'},
                    {label:'Airfare'},
                     {label:'Helicopter'},
        {label:'Hotel'},
                    {label:'Event Regristration'},
                    {label:'Airfare'},
                     {label:'Helicopter'},
         {label:'Hotel'},
                    {label:'Event Regristration'},
                    {label:'Airfare'},
                     {label:'Helicopter'},
         {label:'Hotel'},
                    {label:'Event Regristration'},
                    {label:'Airfare'},
                     {label:'Helicopter'},
                     //labels for axis 2
                      {label:'tourism'},
                    {label:'food'},
                    {label:'lodge'},
                     {label:'stay'},
         {label:'Lion'},
                    {label:'Tiger'},
                    {label:'Limca'},
                     {label:'Coke'},
         {label:'Genius'},
                    {label:'Thumsup'},
                    {label:'Police'},
                     {label:'Progs'},
        {label:'Keys'},
                    {label:'dingo'},
                    {label:'Bingo'},
                     {label:'xingo'},
         {label:'wow1'},
                    {label:'delta2'},
                    {label:'Alpha1'},
                     {label:'Bravo2'},
         {label:'delta3'},
                    {label:'Bravo3'},
                    {label:'Airfare'},
                     {label:'Charlie'},
                ],


        legend:{
            renderer: $.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer,
            show: true,
        //numberRows:0,numberColumns:1,
        //show: true,location:'s',placement:'outside'

        },
         highlighter: {
                show: true,
                sizeAdjust: 7.5,


              },
              cursor: {
                show: false
              },



            };

            plot1 = jQuery.jqplot ('chart1', data, opts);

            var legendTable = $($('.jqplot-table-legend')[0]);    
            legendTable.css('display','block');
            legendTable.css('z-index',100);
            legendTable.css('height','100px');
            legendTable.css('width','100px');
            legendTable.css('overflow-y','scroll');
            legendTable.css('overflow-x','scroll');
        //--------------code for ticks overlap:: @Ashwni--------------------------//

        console.log("ticks length"+ticks.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < ticks.length; i++){
        var len=ticks[i].length;
        console.log("len of a tick"+len);

        console.log($($('.jqplot-xaxis-tick')[i]).css('width'));
        //-------------calculation of factor Delta---------//
        var delta = parseInt($($('.jqplot-xaxis-tick')[i]).css('width'))/(len);
        console.log("delta"+delta*len);
        //-------------Delta calculation ends ------------//


        ($($('.jqplot-xaxis-tick')[i])).wrap('<div id="#chartdiv0" style="width:80px; height:10px; border:1px solid; overflow-x:hidden;float:left;position:absolute">');


        };
        //---------------------------Tick overlap ends@Ashwni-------------------//

        for (var i = 0; i < ticks.length; i++){

        //scroll(i);
        plot(i);
        }
         function plot(i){

        $($('.jqplot-xaxis-tick')[i]).css('z-index',100);

         $($('.jqplot-xaxis-tick')[i]).bind('mouseover', function () {

                   var m= '-webkit-marquee';



                $($('.jqplot-xaxis-tick')[i]).css('overflow-x',m);

           }).bind('mouseout', function () {
         var m= '';
        $($('.jqplot-xaxis-tick')[i]).css('overflow-x',m);

         });


         }
         //$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
         function scroll(i){
         var tWidth = '50px'; // width (in pixels)
        var tHeight = '25px'; // height (in pixels)
        var tcolour = '#ffffcc'; // background colour:
        var moStop =true; // pause on mouseover (true or false)
        var fontfamily = 'arial,sans-serif'; // font for content
        var tSpeed = 3; // scroll speed (1 = slow, 5 = fast)
        // enter your ticker content here (use \/ and \' in place of / and ' respectively)
        //var content = 'Are you looking for loads of useful information <a href="http:\/\/javascript.about.com\/">About //Javascript<\/a>? Well now you\'ve found it.';
        var content =$($('.jqplot-xaxis-tick')[i]);
        console.log(($('.jqplot-xaxis-tick')[i]));
        var cps = -tSpeed;
        var aw, mq;
        var fsz = parseInt(tHeight) - 4;

        function scrollticker() {
            mq.style.right = (parseInt(mq.style.right) > (-10 - aw)) ? mq.style.right = parseInt(mq.style.right) + cps + "px" : parseInt(tWidth) + 10 + "px";
        }

        function startticker() {
            if (document.getElementById) {
                var tick = '<div style="position:relative;width:' + tWidth + ';height:' + tHeight + ';overflow:hidden;background-color:' + tcolour + '"';
                if (moStop) tick += ' onmouseover="cps=0" onmouseout="cps=-tSpeed"';
                tick += '><div id="mq" style="position:absolute;right:0px;top:0px;font-family:' + fontfamily + ';font-size:' + fsz + 'px;white-space:nowrap;"><\/div><\/div>';
                document.getElementById('ticker').innerHTML = tick;
                mq = document.getElementById("mq");
                mq.style.right = (10 + parseInt(tWidth)) + "px";
                mq.innerHTML = '<span id="tx">' + content + '<\/span>';
                aw = document.getElementById("tx").offsetWidth;
                lefttime = setInterval(scrollticker, 50);
            }
        }
        startticker();
        window.onload = startticker;};
        //$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$

        //----Code for adding Ticks Name@ToolTip----------- 
          $("#chart1").bind('jqplotMouseMove', function(ev, gridpos, datapos, neighbor, plot) {
            if (neighbor) {
                $(".jqplot-highlighter-tooltip").html("" + plot.axes.xaxis.ticks[neighbor.pointIndex] + ", " + datapos.yaxis.toFixed(2));
            }
        }); 

        })
        })

        </script>

  </html>
```

Comment: That's quite the wall of code. Could you limit it to the relevant parts?

Comment: u seriouly need to learn, formatting your codes.. :) .. i give up... tired my best :) :)

Comment: I am sorry bipen ! i am referring to  ($($('.jqplot-xaxis-tick')[i])).wrap('<div id="#chartdiv0" style="width:80px; height:10px; border:1px solid; overflow-x:hidden;float:left;position:absolute">');


        };